# Expose a WinForms UserControl as an ActiveX control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, vb6, activex

How do you expose an WinForms UserControl written in C# as an ActiveX control?  My goal is to then use this UserControl from other languages such as VB6 or Delphi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use the Interop Toolkit, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb419144 and http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb-interop/VB6InteropToolkit2.aspx.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to create a [Runnable Callable Wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe.aspx) or [COM Callable Wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f07c8z1c.aspx) depending on your direction.