# Control arrays of Interop UserControls are not supported?

Tags: .net, winforms, vb6, user-controls, vb6-migration

As noted [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7411292/3195477), it is possible to use the Interop Forms Toolkit to create a wrapper around a Winforms usercontrol so that it can be utilized in an ActiveX context, like on a VB6 or PowerBuilder form.

The toolkit includes documentation which states:

> **Interop UserControl limitations**
>
> Interop UserControls are .NET controls, and as such there are a few
>   limitations when using them in Visual Basic 6.0.
>
> - *Control arrays of Interop UserControls are not supported.*

(specifically, file `InteropUserControlsOverview.html`).

What is the reason for the restriction that control arrays can't be used? Is there a workaround?

It is very common to use control arrays in VB6 applications which may be a significant hindrance to some of the migration work I am contemplating.

Thanks

Comment: It's pretty common, in .Net, to have a `List(Of Control)` or an `[Array()] As Control`, `Dictionary(Of Integer, Control)` or `List(Of Whatever)`. Won't do?

Comment: For what its worth, **_not supported_** does not necessarily equal **will not work**.  That list also excludes using them in Office and I have never had an issue with that.  Give it a try.  Side note: the default templates will be configured as 'Any CPU' when used in modern VS versions.  Change that to x86.

Comment: @Jimi its referring to arrays of controls in VB6; so the arrays themselves are VB6 constructs although the objects they would be containing are .NET

Comment: @TnTinMn that's a good tip / interpretation... thanks

Comment: I was referring to *the migration work I am contemplating*. I suppose you are migrating VB6 projects to .Net, not to VB5 :). If you migrate to .Net, you should really use .Net tools, otherwise you'll always be *behind* in a way or another. The conversion may have a steeper start-up, but it won't quirk and choke after.

Comment: @Jimi :) yes, not migrating to VB5!  Our migration is going in stages, gradually replacing VB6 elements with .Net elements. I have some .Net controls which I may substitute for VB6 custom controls as one of those steps.

Comment: Yep, that's the hard part: migrating ActiveX controls/third party stuff. The Control Array to Collection of Controls part is the easiest thing to handle. It's almost the same and it's also easy to debug while converting. Just my personal opinion: I don't agree with *gradually replacing VB6 elements*. It will come out that a good part of the original design and inner logic needs to be redefined from the base up. *Gradually* could mean patch over patch, introducing bugs over bugs. I think it's better to sit down, get some pens and paper and redesign each part.

Comment: As suggested by @TnTinMn I gave it a try and it seemed to work well.

Comment: @Jimi fortunately in my case there are some pretty clear modular boundaries in the app being migrated, so the stepwise migration is pretty clean. These controls may or may not be an example of that.